# How to change each character in a string to the previous character in the alphabet

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to change each character in a string to the previous value in the alphabet. Essentially, I need to create a for each loop that will take every character in a string and increment it backwards by 1.  For instance, I would like to change bcd234% to abc123$.

I have tried breaking the string into an array and subtracting 1 from each element.

```
$myString = "bcd234%"
$myArray = $myString.ToCharArray()
$myArray = $myArray | ForEach-Object { $_ - 1 }
$myArray
-join($myArray)
```

I would expect that it would iterate the value down 1 and then join all of the new values together.

What I would like to see is the new string:
abc123$

What it is actually doing is creating new values for each of the characters and joining them together instead.

The results I am getting are the new array:
97
98
99
49
50
51
36

And then it joins them together which looks like:
97989949505136

Comment: `$_ - 1` -> `[char]([int]$_ - 1)`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I knew it had to be the letters throwing it off.  This did the trick, thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: How do I mark this as answered correctly by you?

Comment: I didn't have the time for writing an actual answer earlier today, so I posted just a comment (which cannot be accepted). I just added an answer with a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you're subtracting an integer from a char PowerShell automatically converts the char to an integer for the calculation. Essentially `$_ - 1` does the same as `([int]$_) - 1`. For getting back a character you can simply cast the result of the operation back to a char.

```
$myArray = $myArray | ForEach-Object { [char]([int]$_ - 1) }
```

The `[int]` is redundant, as mentioned above, but I put it in for good measure, so it's more obvious what is happening there.